# iCal: duration vs dtend?

Tags: icalendar, duration

There seem to be two ways to define the end of an event in iCal. One by using duration and the other one by using dtend. Do either of them have any benefits over the other? I can't find any info other then that dtend seem to override duration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an event and change the 'dtstart', the end time of the event;

1. should not change if you specify 'dtend'
2. should shift if you specify 'duration'

[RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) says

> ```
> ; either 'dtend' or 'duration' may appear in
> ```

```
; a 'eventprop', but 'dtend' and 'duration'
; MUST NOT occur in the same 'eventprop'
```

Answer (score 1):

the DTEND is definitely the better way.
Both of them work but DTEND is also supported in other applications as Cals.
For example Mac Finder or Preview.[One see the ending-time in the left finder icon with the property DTEND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZadB8.png)